# How do I call a function that's in a table, which is indexed by a string that I get from another function, and I also need to add arguments?

Tags: function, lua, arguments, lua-table

I have a table of functions that needs an argument and the functions are labelled with a string

```
local tbl = {fnct1 = function(x), fnct2 = function(x), ...}
```

That string do I get in a table that I returned from another function.

```
fnct1 = str[1]
```

These function should return a table.
Where do I put the argument when I call the function?
This doesn't seem to work:

```
table = tbl[str[1](x)]
```

Comment: Try `tbl[str[1]](x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lhf stated:

```
tbl[str[1]](x)
```

It might help to know that *a function is a value*.

Syntactically, you "acquire" any value through an expression. If you're acquiring a value that you think is a function, you can call it.

The syntax for a function call is the expression for the value followed by parentheses with 0 or more parameter expressions between.

So, `tbl[str[1]]` is an expression and the call is signified by `(` and `)` and `x` is the expression for one parameter. Both expressions are evaluated and the call is attempted. If the expression before the parentheses did not evaluate to a function value, you get an runtime error.

Breaking it down further, *a table is a value* that aggregates key-value pairs with unique keys. (The key is a value and the "value" is a value.) To obtain a "value" from a table, you index the table with the key. The prototypical syntax is: `expression0 [ expression1 ]`, where `expression0` should evaluate to a table value and `expression1` should evaluate to the key value. You can apply that recursively to `tbl[str[1]]`.

[As a convenience, if a key is a string that meets the rules for identifiers, you can index with the `.` operator (or, combined with a function call, the `:` operator).]

Answer (score 1):

Where you usually put the arguments? After the function.

So, if function is `tbl[str[1]]`, just add them right after as always: `tbl[str[1]](args)`.